# Is there any open-source Windows Event-Log analyzer application?

Tags: open-source, event-log

It's my daily routine to check and view my server's Event Log. 
Is there any application to analyze the Windows Event Log and send me notification or report?

I saw many Commercial application when I was googling like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/product) , but any idea about open source desktop application?

Comment: If you could possibly specify your requirements a little bit better, then you could contact me via e-mail [I wrote such a beast - open in mind - but have never published it]. Sorry, I saw this very late ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Snare](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/index.html)
- [AdventNet free edition](http://www.filebuzz.com/fileinfo/15486/AdventNet_EventLog_Analyzer_Free_Edition.html)

Answer (score 2):

ManageEngine's Event Log Analyzer (a division of Zoho Corporation (formerly AdventNet)) offers free event log monitoring tool. It is a full function free tool with 5 hosts limit.

Link: https://www.manageengine.com/products/eventlog/download-free.html

Answer (score 1):

There is [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) but if you are going to buy something, then buy TriGeo's stuff.